# Buildbox game to Test Flight

Tags: android, ios, buildbox

I am a new indie game studying code currently. However I built a Buildbox game and the only Apple export they offer is to the App Store. How do I export this Buildbox game to Apple Test Flight?

I tried to convert it from .bbdoc to .aab, it was a failure.